# VPN that works in China as of October 2017

Tags: china, internet

I’m going to China and want to access my Gmail/Facebook account from time to time. Can somebody recommend a VPN provider or protocol that is not blocked by the Chinese firewall.

I have a private VPN based on OpenVPN and I’m not sure if I can use it in China. As I read, in the recent months they start blocking the OpenVPN protocol completely.

It would be helpful if somebody who is in China now and uses a VPN could give me some advice. Links to blog post older than a month are not helpful.

Comment: In particular see this answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/87049/9009

Comment: Generally, I encourage you to install multiple apps in advance and try them out once you get on China. Many iOS/Mac apps provide free trials (and on Android there should be more), and they would be enough to get through your trip to China.

Comment: I think I go with ExrpessVPN according to their website it should work. It would be nice if somebody using it in China could confirm that.